# Error on printing arrays

Tags: php, html

Those days i'm trying to do an encryption function, but on the last hourse i have been some issues on it.

First of all i made the function work with only letters and symbols and work perfect, but when i add numbers all starts to go wrong.

There goes the code without the numbers:

```
function encryptVerman($text, $length_text) {

//GLOBAL VARIABLES

$textToNumbersArray = array("A" => 0, "B" => 1, "C" => 2, "D" => 3, "E" => 4, "F" => 5, "G" => 6,"H" => 7, "I" => 8, "J" => 9, "K" => 10, "L" => 11, "M" => 12, "N" => 13, "O" => 14, "P" => 15, "Q" => 16, "R" => 17, "S" => 18, "T" => 19, "U" => 20, "V" => 21, "W" => 22, "X" => 23, "Y" => 24, "Z" => 25);

$numbersToTextArray = array(0 => "A", 1 => "B", 2 => "C", 3 => "D", 4 => "E", 5 => "F", 6 => "G", 7 => "H", 8 => "I", 9 => "J", 10 => "K", 11 => "L", 12 => "M", 13 => "N", 14 => "O", 15 => "P", 16 => "Q", 17 => "R", 18 => "S", 19 => "T", 20 => "U", 21 => "V", 22 => "W", 23 => "X", 24 => "Y", 25 => "Z");

$characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

//KEY

$charactersLength = strlen($characters);

$key = "";

for ($i=0; $i < $length_text; $i++) { 

    $key .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];

    $key = (string)$key;
}

//1. KEY AND TEXT TO NUMBERS

$keyToNumbers = array();

$textToNumbers = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($key); $i++) { 

        foreach ($textToNumbersArray as $key_foreach_to => $value_foreach_to) {     

            if ($key[$i] == $key_foreach_to) {

                $keyToNumbers[] = (int)$value_foreach_to;
            } 

            if ($text[$i] == $key_foreach_to) {

                $textToNumbers[] = (int)$value_foreach_to;
            } 
        }
    }

//2. SUM BETWEEN KEYNUMBERS AND TEXTNUMBERS

$sumKeyAndText = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($keyToNumbers); $i++) { 

    $sumKeyAndText[] = ($keyToNumbers[$i] + $textToNumbers[$i]);

    if ($sumKeyAndText[$i] > 25) {

        $sumKeyAndText[$i] = $sumKeyAndText[$i] - 26;
    } else {

        $sumKeyAndText[$i];
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < count($sumKeyAndText); $i++) { 
    echo $key . " Key" . "<br>";
    echo $text . " Text" . "<br>";
    echo $keyToNumbers[$i] . " Key to Numbers" . "<br>";
    echo $textToNumbers[$i] . " Text to Numbers" . "<br>";
    echo $sumKeyAndText[$i] . " Sum Key and Text" . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

And here the html form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 

    include("includes/encrypt.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $text = "";

        $text = $_POST["text"];

        $text = strtoupper($text);

        $text_length = strlen($text);

        $text = (string)$text;

        echo encryptVerman($text, $text_length);

    }

?>
```

[image]

And then when we add the numbers in the two arrays and into the random key generator and we sum up 10 to the if method appears the issues.

First of all, if the key isn't a number the opeartion is done twice. However when the key is a letter the operatios is done twice.

The code with numbers:

```
function encryptVerman($text, $length_text) {

//GLOBAL VARIABLES

$textToNumbersArray = array("A" => 0, "B" => 1, "C" => 2, "D" => 3, "E" => 4, "F" => 5, "G" => 6,"H" => 7, "I" => 8, "J" => 9, "K" => 10, "L" => 11, "M" => 12, "N" => 13, "O" => 14, "P" => 15, "Q" => 16, "R" => 17, "S" => 18, "T" => 19, "U" => 20, "V" => 21, "W" => 22, "X" => 23, "Y" => 24, "Z" => 25, "0" => 26, "1" => 27, "2" => 28, "3" => 29, "4" => 30, "5" => 31, "6" => 32, "7" => 33, "8" => 34, "9" => 35);

$numbersToTextArray = array(0 => "A", 1 => "B", 2 => "C", 3 => "D", 4 => "E", 5 => "F", 6 => "G", 7 => "H", 8 => "I", 9 => "J", 10 => "K", 11 => "L", 12 => "M", 13 => "N", 14 => "O", 15 => "P", 16 => "Q", 17 => "R", 18 => "S", 19 => "T", 20 => "U", 21 => "V", 22 => "W", 23 => "X", 24 => "Y", 25 => "Z", 26 => "0", 27 => "1", 28 => "2", 29 => "3", 30 => "4", 31 => "5", 32 => "6", 33 => "7", 34 => "8", 35 => "9");

$characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

//KEY

$charactersLength = strlen($characters);

$key = "";

for ($i=0; $i < $length_text; $i++) { 
    $key .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    $key = (string)$key;
}

//1. KEY AND TEXT TO NUMBERS

$keyToNumbers = array();

$textToNumbers = array();

for ($i=0; $i < strlen($key); $i++) { 

    foreach ($textToNumbersArray as $key_foreach_to => $value_foreach_to) {     

        if ($key[$i] == $key_foreach_to) {
            $keyToNumbers[] = (int)$value_foreach_to;
        } 

        if ($text[$i] == $key_foreach_to) {
            $textToNumbers[] = (int)$value_foreach_to;
        } 
    }

}

//2. SUM BETWEEN KEYNUMBERS AND TEXTNUMBERS

$sumKeyAndText = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($keyToNumbers); $i++) { 

    $sumKeyAndText[] = ($keyToNumbers[$i] + $textToNumbers[$i]);

    if ($sumKeyAndText[$i] > 35) {
        $sumKeyAndText[$i] = $sumKeyAndText[$i] - 36;
    } else {
        $sumKeyAndText[$i];
    }

}

for ($i=0; $i < count($sumKeyAndText); $i++) { 
    echo $key . " Key" . "<br>";
    echo $text . " Text" . "<br>";
    echo $keyToNumbers[$i] . " Key to Numbers" . "<br>";
    echo $textToNumbers[$i] . " Text to Numbers" . "<br>";
    echo $sumKeyAndText[$i] . " Sum Key and Text" . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you clear with your codes?

Comment: I found the error. What was happening is that the "0" on the array was recived as a null value, so i changed it for a "zero" and then it worked. After i only needed to convert the "zero" into a "0" and it was done!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. What was happening is that the "0" on the array was recived as a null value, so i changed it for a "zero" and then it worked. After i only needed to convert the "zero" into a "0" and it was done!